# Error in rbind, object not found

Tags: r, rbind

EDIT: As suggested below, I can provide with an example, but the problem I assume is not in the code, but something related to the environment as the code works perfectly well when I load it into the GlobalEnvironment, but it gives this error when I load it from my package.
Saying so, loading here 2 data frames wouldn't help at all.

I have a simple function which imports a csv, filters a couple of variables, and merges it with a data.frame which exists already on the global environment.

```
#' Imports file and merges
#' @export
#'

funcTest <- function(x = NULL, m, Q){

    # Imports file
    df1 <- fread(x, header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = TRUE,
                           integer64 = "numeric")

    # Create Filter
    df1 <- df1 %>%
      select(ORIGIN, DEST, ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID, DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID,
             PASSENGERS, QUARTER) %>%
      filter(PASSENGERS > 0, QUARTER == Q) %>%
      select(ORIGIN, DEST, ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID, DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID, PASSENGERS)


  # Merges df1 with df2
  df2 <- df2 %>%
    select(ORIGIN, DEST, ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID, DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID, PASSENGERS)

dfbind <- rbind(df2,df1)

  dfbind <<- dfbind

}
```

Note: m is the data.frame that already exists, and Q is a variable for filtering.

However I run into the error saying that df1 doesn't exist.
If I run the function from the .GlobalEnv, everything works well. If it's on my package, I get this. Any reason for this to be happening?

Comment: The problem is probably one of path to the `csv` that you are trying to read. That is just a guess, though, since you haven't given enough details.

Comment: @JohnColeman The path is correct. I can try to create an example data.frame, but as I've wrote, if I load the function into my 'GlobalEnv', it works well.
The problem is when I load it from my package with devtools::load_all().

Comment: I'm also not sure why the down vote, when this has nothing to do with the data.frame but with the way the function exists/is built. Reading the text above explains it well.

Comment: I didn't downvote you and can't speak for whoever did, but on the R tag there is a strong emphasis on giving a [mcve]. You are asking for debugging help, but no one other than you is able to actually observe the problem.

Comment: Maybe reading this will help: https://www.r-bloggers.com/environments-in-r/  since the problem is almost certainly one of environments.. Also `<<-` is problematic. It potentially has different meanings depending on the environment you invoke it in. I try to avoid it at all costs. If you need something in a parent environment, return it and let the parent environment do the assigning.

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you for the link. My problem with giving an example here is that I honestly can't even think of how would I do that.
I can paste the file, and the data frame, but as the problem only happens inside the package and never when the function is loaded on the GlobalEnvironment, I'm not sure what would even help. I thought it could be a mistake I'm making somehow when assigning variables.

Comment: fread is a data.table function, right? Are you sure you are making that available in your package environment?

Comment: @Martin yes to both questions. The error seems to be somewhere either  `# Create Filter df1 <- df1 %>%` or on the rbind part. It seems that for some reason it doesn't assign the df1 data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the answer was simple and it wasn't related to the code itself. After reading some of the comments above, I realised that both the data.table and dplyr packages weren't being loaded properly into the namespace.
This brought the errors I saw before.

This is a more common error than I thought but often it happens that a solution is never reached. So for those having the same problem, I strongly suggest to check the NAMESPACE file before looking at the function you're using.

Comment: Glad that you found a solution. The way that R handles namespaces and environments can be confusing at times. Even though you already found a solution, this might help: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you a lot for your comment before and even your link now. Actually it was your help before which lead me to this answer. Thank you.